# Answering Tag Questions

Tags: cross-linguistic

I am not sure if the post really is about tag questions. I apologize for the confusion.

Now consider the following situation in English. Your friend asks you,

> Haven't you had lunch?

If you **haven't**, you would say **"no"**, because in English people answer according to the truth of the situation. In Chinese, however, people would say **"yes"**, since they agree with the friend that they haven't had lunch.

Now I am wondering whether this difference is prevalent and where it came from. Also, since it is not a tag question, what is the right term here?

---

### EDIT

I came across "rhetorical question" and "negative question" on Wikipedia as well but was not sure what exactly those two terms meant. I knew it wasn't a tag question but used the term nevertheless because [tag question](http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-questions-tag-answering.htm) works the same way.

Comment: No, that's not a tag question.  Examples of tag questions would be the "have you" in "You've had lunch, have you?" or the "haven't you" in "You've had lunch, haven't you?"  This is still a good question, just not quite the right terminology.

Comment: I came across "rhetorical question" and "negative question on Wikipedia as well but was not sure what exactly those two were referring to. I knew it wasn't a tag question but used it nevertheless because http://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-questions-tag-answering.htm works the same way. Thank you!

Comment: I've heard them referred to as "biased questions," but I'm not sure how widespread that term is.  You might be interested in http://www.sfb632.uni-potsdam.de/publications/isis08_1asher.pdf

Answer (score 2):

This is what is usually called a ***Yes/No Question***. The rules for English Y/N Qs are:

1. Invert subject and first auxiliary verb, add question intonation:

   - ***Bill is** going to the show. --> **Is Bill** going to the show?*
2. If there isn't an auxiliary verb, use ***do***, transfer the tense to *do*, and invert **it**.

   - ***Bill went** to the show --> **Did Bill go** to the show?*
3. If there is a contraction with the first auxiliary verb, the whole contraction may be inverted:

   - ***Bill wasn't** going to the show --> **Wasn't Bill** going to the show?*

Thus the negative is just a normal part of the question, in the normal place, so the grammar is nothing special. The meaning, however, is rather specialized, and there's a big literature on it in pragmatics, among other places.

The pragmatic solution is to note that if a special word is added to a question, but the modified question asks for the same information as the unmodified one, then there must be a special conventional meaning for the added word, right? -- but it doesn't have to be obvious. Since it's a request for information either way, the negation is used to signal speaker expectation.

And since it's **not** about the logical implications of the question, English speakers don't even notice the logic, and answering a negative question with a negative when you agree feels very strange to us; we're keeping our minds on the expectations, beliefs, and goals of the speaker.

Normally English speakers use a negative Y/N Q to suggest that the positive -- **not** the negative -- is what they expect. Thus:

- *Is he going to do it?* (no special implication, just a speaker request for information)
- *Isn't he going to do it?* (implies speaker had expected him to do it, but now doubts)

As others have pointed out, this is not a Tag Question; Tag Qs are tags, on the end of statements. (I'm sure you understand this now, don't you? :-) They have [some interesting syntax](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/tags.pdf), too. But the implications of positive and negative Tag Qs can be confusing when compared with those of regular Y/N Qs.

- *He's going to do it, isn't he?* (negative tag; speaker expected positive statement)
- *He's isn't going to do it, is he?* (positive tag; speaker expected negative statement)

These, by the way, have two different implications, depending on whether *is he?* (or *isn't he?*) has Y/N Q (rising) intonation, which is a real question, or ordinary full stop intonation (like a Wh-Q gets), which is simply a rhetorical question, stating the speaker's belief, and requires no response, though it often invites one.